# Using printwriter to create a text file with several rows from a list

Tags: java, csv, printwriter

I am trying to create a comma separated file in text format and by using try and catch. To do that I am using the library PrintWriter. However, I haven't been able to print all the lines after each other. I created a list to store each line I am creating in each iteration and then I tried using a for over the list to print each element as a row in the file:

```
for(int i=0;i<listA.size();i++) {
    writer.println(listA.get(i));
}
```

However, the result I am getting in the file is

```
Name_DS_1,LineString_1,UFI_1,Name_DS_2,LineString_2,UFI_2
Name1,Line1,Ufi1,Name2,Line2,Ufi2
```

I am expecting:

```
Name_DS_1,LineString_1,UFI_1,Name_DS_2,LineString_2,UFI_2
Name1,Line1,Ufi1,Name2,Line2,Ufi2
Name1,Line1,Ufi1,Name2,Line2,Ufi2
Name1,Line1,Ufi1,Name2,Line2,Ufi2
```

My whole code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static List listA = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        matchSplits();
    }

    public static void matchSplits()
    {
        String header = "Name_DS_1" + "," + "LineString_1" + "," + "UFI_1" + "," + "Name_DS_2" + "," + "LineString_2" + "," + "UFI_2" + "\r\n";
        String fileName = "D:\\WIP\\test\\Coordinates.txt";  
        File file = new File(fileName);      
        int matchCount = 0;

        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)) {
            for (int k=0;k<3;k++) {
                //Here I am inserting the header only in the first iteration. 
                if(matchCount == 0) {
                    writer.write(header);
                }

                String Name_DS_1 = "Name1";
                String LineString_1 = "Line1";
                String UFI_1 = "Ufi1";
                String Name_DS_2 = "Name2";
                String LineString_2 = "Line2";
                String UFI_2 = "Ufi2";              
                String line = Name_DS_1 + "," + LineString_1 + "," + UFI_1 + "," + Name_DS_2 + "," + LineString_2 + "," + UFI_2 + "\r\n";

                listA.add(line);

                for(int i=0; i<listA.size(); i++) {
                    writer.println(listA.get(i));
                }

                writer.close();
                matchCount++;
            }                 
        }    
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does what is expected of it. You only seem to have one line, and that means it prints that line once. To get more lines, you need to add more lines.

Comment: `writer.close();`? out side of for loop.

Comment: Thanks @SatyaTNV, that was the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution to your problem, here you can find a solution

```
public class App {
    public static List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        matchSplits();
    }
    public static void matchSplits() {
        String header = "Name_DS_1" + "," + "LineString_1" + "," + "UFI_1" + "," + "Name_DS_2" + "," + "LineString_2" + "," + "UFI_2";
        String fileName = "foo.csv"; // your file name here
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)) {
            // no need to check if k == 0, this is outside the loop
            listA.add(header);
            // prepare your data here
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                String Name_DS_1 = "Name1";
                String LineString_1 = "Line1";
                String UFI_1 = "Ufi1";
                String Name_DS_2 = "Name2";
                String LineString_2 = "Line2";
                String UFI_2 = "Ufi2";
                String line = Name_DS_1 + "," + LineString_1 + "," + UFI_1 + "," + Name_DS_2 + "," + LineString_2 + "," + UFI_2;
                listA.add(line);
            }
            // write your lines here
            for (String s: listA) {
                writer.println(s);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

A few tips:

- There is no need for closing the `PrintWriter` as you declared it in `try(...)`
- There is no need for `\r\n` as you are already using `printline`
- There is no need for two counters, `k` is enough (at least in this snippet)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have written writer.close() in the scope of for loop. 
for (int k=0;k<3;k++)

Try removing writer.close() statement.
As this statement is closing the writing process when k=0 only.

Because the PrintWriter instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly if these resources implements AutoCloseable interface.

Try doing this, Hope it will solve your problem :)